Tengo un problema con PHP
Tengo 2 formularios (maestros) que el primero registra estado, y lo guarda en la base de datos. En el otro formulario tengo un select que me trae todos los registros que yo haya hecho en el formulario estado y tengo un input de texto donde se guarda el municipio.
Ejemplo, yo selecciono un estado y escribo un municipio, y se guarda en la base de datos el id_estado y el nombre_municipio en una tabla que tiene relacion con estado, ejemplo en SQL:
Table estado(
   id_estado INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nombre_estado (40) VARCHAR
);
Table municipio(
  id_estado INT (10),
  id_municipio INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre_municipio VARCHAR (40), 
  FOREIGN KEY (id_estado) REFERENCES estado(id_estado)
);

Y ahi esta la relacion de mis tablas
Mi formulario:
<form action="../controlador/ctl_municipio.php" method="post" name="formulario-municipio">
          <div>
            <label>Estado:</label>
            <div>
              <select name="id_estado" id="estado">
                <option value="" selected>...</option>
                <?php while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                  ?>

          <?php echo "<option value='" . $row['id_estado'] . "'>" .$row['nombre_estado'];?>
               <?php echo"</option>"?>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form>
              <div>
                <label name="nombre-municipio">Nombre De Municipio:</label>
                <div>
       <input type="text" id="nombre-municipio" name="nombre_municipio" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <button name="registar" value="registrar" type="submit">Registrar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
           </form>

Y ahora como el ámbito es modelo, vista, controlador, el Controlador es el siguiente:
<?php

include("../modelo/conexion.php");  // Incluir el archivo para la conexion
include("../modelo/clase_municipio.php");  // Incluir el archivo de la clase

$per = new Municipio();  // Creo el objeto de la clase  

############################################################################
### REGISTRAR ##############################################################
############################################################################
// Verifica que se alla presionado el boton especifico
if(isset($_POST['registrar']) && $_POST['registrar']=="registrar"){
    // Setear las variables o propiedades
    $per->setIdEstado($_POST['id_estado']);
    $per->setMunicipio($_POST['nombre_municipio']);

    // Invocamos al método de Registrar
    $datos = $per->RegistrarMunicipio($per->getIdEstado(),$per->getMunicipio()); 
    // Si el método retorna un arreglo vacío
    if(empty($datos)){
        echo "<script>alert('No se pudo registrar los datos.!!!')</script>"; // Mensaje de Registro NO válida
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=../vista/Ubicaciones/Municipio.html'>"; // Regresar a la pantalla para registrar
    }else{  // Si el areglo contiene datos retornó 1            
        echo "<script>alert('Registrado con exito.!!!')</script>"; // Mensaje satisfactorio
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=../vista/Ubicaciones/Municipio.html'>"; // Regresar a la pantalla inicial que LISTA los registros
    }
}
?>

Ahora la clase:
class Municipio {
    // DECLARACION DE LAS PROPIEDADES
    // Variables
    public $id_estado, $nombre_municipio;

    // Setters
    public function setIdEstado($id_estado){ $this->id_estado = $id_estado; }
    public function setMunicipio($nombre_municipio){ $this->nombre_municipio = $nombre_municipio; }

    // Getters
    public function getIdEstado(){ return $this->id_estado; }
    public function getMunicipio(){ return $this->nombre_municipio; }

    ############################################################################
    ### REGISTRAR ##############################################################
    ############################################################################
    // DECLARACION DE UN METODO
    public function RegistrarMunicipio($id_estado,$nombre_municipio){
        // Se llama al archivo para la conexion
        include("conexion.php");
        
         
        // Sentencia sql para Consultar
        $sql = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM municipio WHERE id_estado = ? AND nombre_municipio = ?;");
        // Enviar los valores
        $sql->execute([$id_estado,$nombre_municipio]);
        // Numero de resultado encontrado
        $num = $sql->rowCount();
        // Si NO existe un registro
        if (!$num){
            // Sentencia sql para Registrar 
            $sql = $conex->prepare("INSERT INTO municipio (id_estado,nombre_municipio) VALUES (?,?);");
            // Ejecuta la sentencia sql enviando los valores
            $insertar = $sql->execute([$id_estado,$nombre_municipio]);
            // Retornar 1 el resultado de la sentencia sql
            return $insertar;
        }else{
            // Se asigna cero
            $num = $num - 1;
            // Retornar 0 (cero) indicando que ya existe el registro 
            return $num;
        }
        // Cerramos la conexion
        mysqli_close($conex);
    } // FIN function Registrar

    
}

Al registrar me da error todo esto. Disculpen todo el texto pero si alguien me pueda ayudar, será bien recibido, gracias!

Pulsa en [edit] y describe tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta el problema específico que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Tienes dos name="nombre-municipio" en dos elementos distintos dentro del form.  Como no indicas QUE error te da, poco más puedo decirte, eso es lo que he visto a ojímetro.

Según veo, tienes dos etiquetas de apertura <form ...> y una sola etiqueta de cierre </form>, lo cual es erróneo. Decide qué es lo que quieres, si dos formularios distintos que reaccionen de forma independiente o un solo formulario con selects dependientes. Usar Ajax o Fetch para resolver este tipo de problemas evita confusiones y permite escribir un código más moderno.

Gracias, lo de las etiquetas form no me había fijado, arregle eso y aún sigue el error, lo que pasa es que soy novato en esto, y por lo menos no tengo como identificar los errores ya que no se, me falta por aprender, y lo de Ajax y fetch no se sobre eso, tengo que aprender un poco sobre ello

Faltaba una r en registrar

Aparte de lo dicho más arriba, estás mezclando dos APIs para interactuar con la base de datos. Por un lado, tienes funciones de PDO y por otro funciones de mysqli. Debes usar una u otra. En cuanto a revisar los errores, conviene que aprendas a manejar el log de errores. Te va a ahorrar muuuuchas horas y muuuuchos rompederos de cabeza. Revisa esta pregunta para más detalles.
